# SQL Server Date Selection

Tags: sql-server-2005

Update
How to write query on sql server to check

case IsValidDate(Date) then  Date+ ' days ' worked
when IsEmptyorNUll(Date) then '*****'

Comment: Have you got any indexes defined on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

`AND CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), AUDIT_DATE + ' ' +AUDIT_TIME ,101) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN 'Jan 1 2000 12:00AM' AND 'Jul 7 2010 12:00AM' ORDER BY CAST((AUDIT_DATE ) AS DATETIME), CAST((AUDIT_TIME ) AS DATETIME), AUDIT_ID` is pure evil - and will render any index on AUDIT_DATE / AUDIT_TIME useless.